# Are dotted and non-dotted Gmail addresses always different?

Tags: gmail, google-account, email

I am receiving very often emails with a dot in the address, such as `jon.doe@gmail.com`, despite  my actual username is *without dot* (`jondoe`).

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en#zippy=%2Cgetting-messages-sent-to-a-dotted-version-of-my-address), dots are irrelevant in Gmail addresses, that is, Google forwards  `jon.doe@gmail.com` to `jondoe@gmail.com`

However, I appear to be subscribed to newsletters (such as eBay and Apple) by companies which ask for a confirmation before adding your name in their user database, so I could receive at most the initial confirmation message. I contacted Apple phone support, and a person told me that there has been an *issue with Google addresses*  in the past, which gave the possibility to sign up with both `jon.doe` and `jondoe` usernames. She herself had my same issue and suggested to contact Google to have it fixed.

While I have not yet been able to receive answers from Google, I have found a Quora [link](https://www.quora.com/My-Gmail-address-includes-a-dot-and-now-I-get-the-emails-of-the-person-who-doesnt-have-the-dot-How-do-I-prevent-that-I-receive-all-the-junk-he-subscribes-to-I-got-my-address-over-10-years-ago), confirming the Apple claim regarding the dot requirement:

> Somewhere around 2011ish IIRC this requirement was removed when they started ignoring dots in addresses. [...] suddenly I received email for firstlast@gmail which was the address I originally wanted.

[and](https://www.quora.com/Does-gmail-differentiate-between-email-addresses-with-dot-and-without-dot)

> ... yes you could now be receiving someone else's email!

So, according to Google, there cannot be both a `jon.doe@gmail.com` and a `jondoe@gmail.com` user. According to other sources, this, at least in the past, was possible, implying that one can receive someone else's email. The latter seems possible, because I am receiving unsolicited emails from companies which are unlikely to spam, and one of them (Apple) confirmed this to be the problem.

Can someone confirm or disprove this?

Comment: As a first step, the emails themselves need to be verified.  Can you edit your question to provide a complete header from one or more of the "legitimate" emails you received through the dot alias?  You can anonymize your email address in the headers using the same method you used in your question: `jondoe@gmail.com`  and `jon.doe@gmail.com`  paste the headers as text in [markdown code blocks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#:~:text=Alternatively%2C%20surround%20the%20text%20by%20three%20or%20more%20backticks%20or%20tildes%3A "format code: 3+ backticks or tildes")